# ¿Como detener codigo hasta que se complete un query utilizando Volley?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, android-asynctask, android-volley

Durante mi proyecto he estado trabajando con Android Studio junto con la librería Volley, hay una parte del código en la cual requiero retirar información de empresas utilizando el formato Json y éste lo convierto en un JsonArray para poder utilizarlo en un adaptador de RecyclerView. El problema está en que la linea de código del adaptador se ejecuta antes de que pueda recibir los datos del servidor, he intentado utilizar el comando Thread.sleep() pero de igual manera sigo obteniendo los mismos resultados. De antemano gracias:) aquí les dejo el código del fragmento:

```
public class FragmentPrincipal extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayout;
ArrayList<itemVacantes> listaVacantes = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_principal, container, false);

    getDatosVacantes(view); //en esta linea se ejecuta el query a la base de datos

    System.out.println(listaVacantes); //aqui la lista llega como nulo

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.infoRecycler);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());

    mAdapter = new adapterVacantes(listaVacantes);//esta linea es la que se ejecuta antes de poder llenar el array con los datos de las vacantes
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return view;
}

private void getDatosVacantes(View v) {
    String url = "http://10.18.232.64/SNE_API/getDatosVacante.php";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(v.getContext());
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("datos");
                System.out.println("jsonarray" + jsonArray); //el array llega de manera correcta

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject vacante = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String oferta = vacante.getString("TituloOferta");
                    String nomEmpresa = vacante.getString("NombreEmpresa");
                    listaVacantes.add(new itemVacantes(R.drawable.ic_person, oferta, nomEmpresa)); //en esta parte la lista si se llena con datos
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Volley` ejecuta las peticiones http de manera [asincrónica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunicaci%C3%B3n_asincr%C3%B3nica), lo que significa que cuando ejecutas una petición, la respuesta de esta se devuelve un tiempo después en forma de callback. Por lo que es muy probable (en la mayoría de los casos) que el código dentro de un callback se ejecute después de el código que esta fuera de este, aunque declares el callback antes de cualquier otro código.

Por lo que para solucionar el problema solo tienes que colocar el código del adaptador dentro del callback `onResponse`.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {

        ...

        mAdapter = new adapterVacantes(listaVacantes);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```